# While Trying to Install Yeomen Getting Warning

Tags: node.js, npm

It is saying upgrade to uuid@3.4.0 to Higher version, How should i deal with it

Please guide me achiving it

```
C:\Program Files>npm install -g yo
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\yo -> C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\lib\cli.js
C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\yo-complete -> C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\lib\completion\index.js
```

Answer (score 0):

These are warnings that are up to the package author(s) to fix (or you have to file a pull request yourself in their repository where you fix it yourself).

If they don't keep their package updated with the newest dependencies, you will see this type of warnings.

Most of the time this is expected in the sense that package authors never manage to be 100% up to date always, and most of the time they will fix it in a later update. And most of the time the package will install correctly and work regardless of the warning. But sometimes these warnings could also imply security issues, which is not the case here, it seems.

If the package doesn't work after you have installed it, you have to file an issue with the yo author(s) or make a pull request to their repository.

Seems to me this install worked after all. You can check if the name of the package is added in your package.json or is found in the node_modules folder.